# PHP script won't pass content on to Ajax call

Tags: php, html, ajax, xml, xhtml

I would like to know what is wrong with my code, it's a very simple ajax call to a php script, but the text in the php script won't get passed on to the html page. What is wrong?

```
<html>
<script>
function checkForm() {

    var pass = document.getElementById("oldpassword").value;
    var pass1 = document.getElementById("passwordnew1").value;
    var pass2 = document.getElementById("passwordnew2").value;

    if (pass == '' || pass1 == '' || pass2 == '') {
        alert("Fill All Fields");
    } else {

        var passcheck = document.getElementById("editpassword");
        var passcheck1 = document.getElementById("equalpasswords1");
        var passcheck2 = document.getElementById("equalpasswords2");

        if (passcheck.innerHTML == 'Must be 3+ letters' || passcheck2.innerHTML == 'Password too short' || passcheck3.innerHTML == 'Invalid email') {
            alert("Fill Valid Information");
        } else {
            document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
        }
    }
}


function validate(field, query) {
    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if (xmlhttp.readyState != 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById(field).innerHTML = "Validating..";
    } else if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById(field).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    } else {
        document.getElementById(field).innerHTML = "Error Occurred. <a     href='index.html'>Reload Or Try Again</a> the page.";
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "validation.php?field=" + field + "&query=" + query, false);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
<body>
    <form action="#" id="myForm" name="passwordform" method="post">
        <div class="container">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:100px"><p><b>My email:</b></td>
                    <td><p><?php print($email); ?></p></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><p><b>My password:</b></td>
                    <td><p id="editpassword"></p><p id="insertpassword"><input type="password"     id="oldpassword" name="inputedPassword" onblur="validate('inputedPassword',  this.value)" value="<?php print($password); ?>"/></p></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><p><b>My new password:</b></td>
                    <td><p id="equalpasswords1"></p><input type="password" id="passwordnew1"  name="Password1" onblur="validate('Password1', this.value)"/></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><p><b>Confirm password:</b></td>
                    <td><p id="equalpasswords2"></p><input type="password" id="passwordnew2"    name="Password2" onblur="validate('Password2', this.value)"/> <input  type="button" value="Save" onclick="checkForm()"></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the php code it calls:

```
<?php
$value = $_GET['query'];
$formfield = $_GET['field'];

if ($formfield == "inputedPassword") {
    if (strlen($value) < 4) {
        echo "Must be 3+ letters";
    } else {
        echo "<span>Valid</span>";
    }
}

if ($formfield == "Password1") {
    if (strlen($value) < 6) {
        echo "Password too short";
    } else {
        echo "<span>Strong</span>";
    }
}

if ($formfield == "Password2") {
    if (strlen($value) < 6) {
        echo "Password too short";
    } else {
        echo "<span>Strong</span>";
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var passcheck = document.getElementById("editpassword");
var passcheck1 = document.getElementById("equalpasswords1");
var passcheck2 = document.getElementById("equalpasswords2");

if (passcheck.innerHTML == 'Must be 3+ letters' || passcheck2.innerHTML == 'Password too short' || passcheck3.innerHTML == 'Invalid email') {
```

Your variable name in the `if` test is incorrect. You're declaring variable `passcheck`, `passcheck1` and `passcheck2` but in your `if` test you're calling `passcheck`, `passcheck2` and `passcheck3`.

Comment: <input type="password" id="`passwordnew2`" name="Password2" onblur="`validate('Password2', this.value)`"/> I think in your validate, the first param should be your input ID, therefore it should be `passwordnew2` instead of `Password2`

Comment: I don't think so. That doesn't work, and here http://www.formget.com/form-validation-using-ajax/ it says it should be the name

Comment: But inside your validate function, it's calling `document.getElementById(field)` so I don't see why you would need the name... since you're calling `document.getElementById`

Comment: I've check the demo you linked. And the first param in the function validate is the `ID` of the `div` tag on the third column of the table which you don't have. So right now, your result is returning no where.

Comment: I don't have it in a new column, I have it in the three paragraphs in the same column. <p id="equalpasswords2"> You see?

Comment: Same thing happens when I add one field to the demo!

Comment: Finally managed. You were right, sorry but couldn't really get what you were saying, thanks so much!!

Comment: Oh my bad I didn't see the reply. Well your `p` ID is `equalpasswords2`, so in your validate function, it should be `validate('equalpassword2', this.value)`

Comment: KayVan, 

I would now like my form to run some PHP code which updates a database. Where should I put this PHP code in the PHP script? I've been thinking about it but I'm quite lost. Thanks!

Comment: Obviously, the form should submit (and database should update) only when all other conditions have been met

Comment: In your `form`, you have an `action` attribute, put the name of a new PHP script there and put the stuff you want in that php file.

Comment: Yes but if I do that then the page will go to that php file. I don't want the page to change, I want the database to update and the page to remain the same!

Comment: Oh, then you will have to use an Ajax call.

Comment: Yes but that's what I have in the code I put up here right? Isn't there a place where I can put the php code which updates the database within the ajax call written above? Once the form gets submitted?

Comment: Add `onsubmit="return submitForm();"` and make a function named `submitForm()` with an ajax call and `return false`. So when you click submit, it will do the Ajax call, and not refresh the page it's calling. And put the database actions you want in the file the ajax is calling.

Comment: My form becomes now: 
<form action="#" id="myForm" name="myForm" method="post" onsubmit="return submitForm();" class="ajaxcall">

Comment: And my script:
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitForm() {
$("document").ready(function(){
  $(".ajaxcall").submit(function(){
    var data = {
      "action": "test"
    };
    data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      url: "updatepassword.php", 
      data: data,
      success: function(data) {
        $("#check").html(
          data["Password2"] 
        );

        
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
}
</script>

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript"> 
 function submitForm() { 
  $.ajax({ 
   type: "POST", 
   dataType: "json", 
   url: "updatepassword.php", 
   data: { oldpassword: $('#oldpassword').val()} , 
   success: function(data) { 
    $("#check").html( data["Password2"] ); 
   } 
  });
  
  return false;
 }); 
</script>` Add your other post variables to the data.